# How do I pass "x-ms-client-principal" in Azure Static Website Hosting (Preview) when running locally?

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-functions, azure-static-website-hosting

I'm trying out the new Azure Static Website Hosting Preview and when running locally, the Azure functions aren't receiving the "x-ms-client-principle" header in the req binding object.

My routes file looks like:

```
{
  "routes": [
    {
      "route": "/api/*",
      "allowedRoles": ["administrator"]
    },
    {
      "route": "/*",
      "serve": "/index.html",
      "statusCode": 200
    }
  ]
}
```

My API function is getting hit at: `/api/message`, but isn't including the header.

```
module.exports = async function (context, req) {
  const header = req.headers["x-ms-client-principal"]; // req.headers doesn't include x-ms-client-principle
  const encoded = Buffer.from(header, "base64");
  const decoded = encoded.toString("ascii");
}
```

The static app is a React static page created with create-react-app. I have a line to print out the result from the react-app:

```
fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API}/message?name=me`)
  .then(a => a.text())
  .then(console.log);
```

Locally `process.env.REACT_APP_API` is set via `REACT_APP_API=http://127.0.0.1:7071/api`.

The API is getting hit, but I'm not sure if it's running the correct version of Azure Functions. It is reporting: `Function Runtime Version: 2.0.12961.0` even though I've installed azure-functions-core-tools@3, and set the proper value (`"azureFunctions.projectRuntime": "~3"`) in `settings.json`.

My question is am I missing something, and if so, what?

Comment: What is 'x-ms-client-principle' refer to? I know `X-MS-CLIENT-PRINCIPAL-NAME` or 'X-MS-CLIENT-PRINCIPAL-ID'.

Comment: x-ms-client-principle comes from the howto at:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/user-information#api-functions

Comment: Have your configured authentication? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/authentication-authorization

Comment: I have, but I'm not sure how it's supposed to actually do the authentication running locally.

Answer (score 2):

For the moment, it appears that this is not a supported scenario per:

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/55517

Answer (score 0):

For anybody stumbling on this one 2022 there's a [CLI](https://github.com/Azure/static-web-apps-cli) and [remember to set the api correctly](https://github.com/Azure/static-web-apps/issues/21#issuecomment-891563910).. Although not trivial to setup it works.